# React Native: how to make View inside ImageBackground have 100% width but with horizontal padding?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-image, imagebackground

I have the following screen in my React Native app:
[image]

The blue black and white background is an `ImageBackground`, and the green strip in the middle is a `View`. The code is:

```
<ImageBackground
  source={require('@images/login-background.jpg')}
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}
>
  <View style={{
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 15,
    padding: 15
  }}/>
  </ImageBackground>
```

I want there to be `15px` of padding at the left and right edges of the green `View`. If the `ImageBackground` were a `View` I would've added `15px` of padding to it, but when it's an `ImageBackground` that results in this:

[image]

Conversely, if I add `margin: 15px` to the green `View`, I get this:

[image]

How should I approach this, to make it look like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the above requirement using `Dimensions` in React-Native

```
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default App = () => (
    <ImageBackground
        source={{ uri: "https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png" }}
        style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            resizeMode: 'cover',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
        <View style={{
            width: screenWidth - 30,
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderRadius: 15,
            padding: 15
        }} />
    </ImageBackground>
);
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Ok yep, this works, thanks! Do you know if there's also a way to do it with padding or margin?

Comment: @gkeenley when you assign ```width: '100%'``` it automatically assign width according to the parent view. you can try adding ```marginHorizontal: 15, width: '90%'``` but that might not be an optimal solution.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately that wouldn't work if the phone's going between portrait and landscape. I'll go ahead and use the Dimensions thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
    <ImageBackground
      source={image}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
    <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 15}}>
      <View style={{
       width: '100%',
       backgroundColor: 'green',
       borderRadius: 15,
       padding: 15,
      }}/>
    </View>
    </ImageBackground>
```

Comment: This is my fallback solution :) I'd rather do it without adding another `View`, but this does work, thank you.